# Access \@email in a custom LaTeX class

Tags: titles, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I am trying to customize an article class for my needs. I want to access `\email{}` in my class but without any success.

This is my `\maketitlepage` section in cls file,

```
\newcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
\begin{center}      
\includegraphics[scale=0.20]{dsg}~\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\LARGE University name}\\[1.0cm]
 \textsc{\Large Institute of Something}\\[0.5cm]
 \HRule \\[0.4cm]    
  {\huge \bfseries\@title \\[0.4cm]}

  \HRule \\[1.5cm]    
  \large          
  \@author\@email                                                                                            
   \vfill
  {\large \@date}     
 \end{center}          
 \end{titlepage}%      
 }
```

I also defined `\email` to be (took it from lncs.cls):

`\def \email#1{{\tt#1}}`

After using this in my article as `\email{john.doe@email.com}` the email is shown on the top of the titlepage, instead of the place where it should land.

I am quite new to creating own classes.

Comment: The LaTeX kernel doesn't define `\email`, so there is no `\@email` 'out of the box'. Are you perhaps looking to define `\@email` (_e.g._ `\newcommand{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}` then use it where it should be printed?

Comment: You need to do `\def\email#1{\def\@email{#1}}`. `{\tt#1}` simply typesets the argument.

Comment: @JosephWright exactly I want to define it and use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel defines only `\author`, `\title` and `\date` for saving 'meta data', for example

```
\newcommand{\author}[1]{\def\@author{#1}}
```

which therefore stores the author list as `\@author` for later use. Thus you can set up `\email` in the same way

```
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}
```

You can then use the e-mail address(es) using `\@email`. I would not just use `\tt`: quite apart from anything else, it is deprecated in favour of `\texttt`/`\ttfamily`. Probably you are best using the `\url` package, *e.g.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}
\newcommand*{\printemail}{\expandafter\url\expandafter{\@email}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{url}

\email{demo@demo_domain.com}

\begin{document}

\printemail

\end{document}
```